# Android Studio: Google Map v2 How to Create Route Made by Multiple Polylines following the Roads Only

Tags: android-studio, kml, google-maps-api-2, mkpolyline

I cant found step by step tutorial about multiple polylines following a route in google maps and I need to code routes using multiple coordinates using Android Studio-Google Map. Ive been searching about weeks now and I don't have a single clue where to start coding multiple polyline that connects to the road to make a route. Any tips would really help me. It is kinda like connecting A->B,B->C,C->D to make a specific route possibly using array of latlng. My project is like bus routes, I need to code many different routes and only show 1 route at a time.

I only found straight polylines, codes like these. Not much of a help to what  I need.

```
 Polyline line = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                        .add(new LatLng(16.416213, 120.582274), new LatLng(16.415246, 120.590181))
                        .width(5)
                        .color(Color.RED));
```

Anyone could give me a better idea or maybe one of kinda a step by step?
A big thanks if you could help me.

Comment: This may be what you are looking for. 
https://inducesmile.com/android/android-real-time-user-location-tracking-using-google-map-api-v2/